# Neck size of wormholes in shape dynamics

Tags: gravity, black-holes, wormholes, machs-principle

As far as a dilettante like me knows, in [shape dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_dynamics), black holes are really wormholes.

What it the expected diameter of the necks of such wormholes (both for regular holes resulting from the collapse of stars, and for big holes in the centers of galaxies)?

Comment: The 'neck' is just the usual event horizon, isn't it? And outside the event horizon, the solution looks the same as Schwarzschild.